# display new lines from xml to html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the data from xml to html via jquery

I have the data in xml in paragraph format, but becuase of html's default behaviour it cannot display the lines which are in form of "enter".

please suggest how can i make sure that it'll start displaying.

my query is very similar to this link which is already done here.

but i don't know how to do it in html/javascript

[Read xml string into textbox with newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214620/read-xml-string-into-textbox-with-newline)

Thanks in advance
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just inserted the iwantenter into the xml file whereever I need enter

and after assigning the text to the div

I called this function

id_of_my_div.replace(/iwantenter/g,'< br > < br >'); and it worked

Thanks Krof for continues replies.

Answer (score 2):

If you're inserting indented XML code, you can use the `white-space: pre` CSS property on the container to display the line breaks:

```
<p style="white-space: pre" id="xmlCode"></p>
```

And in jQuery just set the text:

```
$('#xmlCode').text(xmlContent);
```

Comment: Sorry, should have been `white-space: pre`; I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank Krof, it's working but it's not taking the "Enter" which is there in xml. it's continuing into the one line only

Comment: Unless you're going to manually break lines, there's no way you can have automatic line breaking with `pre` white space. What you can do is set `overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden` on the `p` element to show horizontal scrollbars whenever the lines overflow the width.

Comment: What's the ASCII code for the "Enter" character? Sounds like you're not using `\n` or `\r\n`.

Comment: it's straight forward displaying \r\n in page

Comment: The code above should work if the `xmlContent` variable contains the correct whitespace. If you view the XML content in Notepad or similar, does it show the line breaks correctly?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [jQuery text() call preserves newlines in Firefox but not in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656605/jquery-text-call-preserves-newlines-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie)